# How to make half wheel circle with 8 part. html , css or svg

Tags: html, css, svg

[image]

i need this half wheel part is not specific 4 or 5 which should be dynamic. with react.js.

i tried to make this with html svg but i did't make it dynamic.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please show the code you have tried already, SO isn’t an ab initio coding service I’m afraid but we are very willing to help debug a specific coding problem. Please also expand the description of what you are trying to do. Especially is each one of those segments to be a separate element or are you just wanting that background coloring?

Answer (score 1):

Since React was thrown in the mix, I presume any answer *under* 60 KB is valid.

Here is my **999 Bytes** Web Component, supported in all Modern Browsers...

**HTML:**

```
    <pie-chart>
      <slice size="10" stroke="blue"></slice>
      <slice size="2"  stroke="transparent"></slice>
      <slice size="10" stroke="green"></slice>
      <slice size="2"  stroke="transparent"></slice>
      <slice size="10" stroke="orange"></slice>
      <slice size="2"  stroke="transparent"></slice>
      <slice size="10" stroke="red"></slice>
      <slice size="2"  stroke="transparent"></slice>
      <slice size="10" stroke="purple"></slice>
      <slice size="58" stroke="transparent"></slice>
    </pie-chart>
```

**output:**

[image]

**ALL source code:**

https://pie-meister.github.io/

```html
<script src="https://pie-meister.github.io/PieMeister.min.js"></script>

<pie-chart>
  <slice size="10" stroke="blue"></slice>
  <slice size="2" stroke="transparent"></slice>
  <slice size="10" stroke="green"></slice>
  <slice size="2" stroke="transparent"></slice>
  <slice size="10" stroke="orange"></slice>
  <slice size="2" stroke="transparent"></slice>
  <slice size="10" stroke="red"></slice>
  <slice size="2" stroke="transparent"></slice>
  <slice size="10" stroke="purple"></slice>
  <slice size="58" stroke="transparent"></slice>
</pie-chart>
```